# Trying to scan a string which is a line from a file already scanned

Tags: java, text-files

I have scanned in individual lines from a text file and now need to separate the line into four different strings and then add them to an array. Any help with what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public void method()throws FileNotFoundException{

    FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(mainWindow,"Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileBox.setVisible(true);
    fileBox.setDirectory(".");
    String dataFile = fileBox.getFile();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(dataFile));
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        String lineOfInput = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineOfInput.startsWith("/") || lineOfInput.startsWith("[") && lineOfInput !=null)
        scanner.nextLine();
        else
        {
            String newLineOfInput = lineOfInput.trim();
            System.out.println(newLineOfInput);
            Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(newLineOfInput);
            while(newScanner.hasNext())
            {
                String group = scanner.next();
                String vehID = scanner.next();
                String regNo = scanner.next();
                String make = scanner.next();
                storeVehicle( new Vehicle(group, vehID, regNo,make));
                newScanner.close();
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

    }
```

Comment: You should specify what is happening now.

Answer (score 0):

Just skimmed through question... Seems like the `scanner` in below code should be `newScanner` instead.

```
String group = scanner.next();
String vehID = scanner.next();
String regNo = scanner.next();
String make = scanner.next();
```

Because you want to use the line stored under variable `newLineOfInput`; I assume?

A better alternative would be to use `String#split` function. You won't be creating a whole new `Scanner` object. It would go something like this:

```
String[] lines = newLineOfInput.split(" "); // Splits the string into a string array separated at every 'Space' character.
String group = lines[0];
String vehID = lines[1];
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use a second scanner

Comment: The console displays this msg on run-time - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Unknown Source)
 at ReservationSystem.readVehicleData(ReservationSystem.java:45)
 at Test.main(Test.java:16)

Comment: Add the line `newScanner.close();` outside the loop.

Comment: Still gives me the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            File file = new File( ".txt" );
        Scanner in = null;
        try
        {
            in = new Scanner( file );
            while( in.hasNext() )
            {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                if( line.contains( "" ) )
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Not sure if that will help, but maybe worth a try.